# jQuery - each function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, javascript

I currently have a list of thumbnails that is located in a `ul` tag as `li`'s.

I am using the [Galleria](http://devkick.com/lab/galleria/) image gallery, but I have more than six images in my gallery, so am I trying to implement a page system.

What I am trying to do is the following:

I have a row of images, `row1`, when you click on page 2 `row1` should hide using this function `hide("slide")`, and after all of them have hid, `row2` should show using `show("slide")`, but these `hide` and `show` functions occur at the same time, I want the `hide` function to finish before the `show` function executes, here is my code:

```
$("a[href^='#']").click(function() {
    if (($(this).attr("href") == "#") && ($(this).attr("rel") != "gallery") && ($(this).attr("href").indexOf("row") < 0)) {
        return false;
    }
    else if ($(this).attr("href").indexOf("row") < 0) {
        $.scrollTo($(this).attr("href"),1000);
        return false;
    } else {
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        href = href.replace("#","");
        $("ul.galleria li").each(function() {
            if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
                $(this).hide("slide");
            }
        }).;

        $("ul.galleria li."+href).each(function() {
            $(this).show("slide", 800);
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

How can I have the hide function execute while the show function waits for a go ahead?

// edit

I have changed my code to the following:

```
$("ul.galleria li:visible").hide("clip", {direction : "horizontal"},function(){
    $("ul.galleria li."+href).show("clip", {direction : "horizontal"}, 800);
});
```

But now, the show function runs exactly the number of times as the number of `li`'s that was visible on the previous 'page'. How can I have that function execute only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try changing this:

```
$("ul.galleria li").each(function() {
                if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
                        $(this).hide("slide");
                }
        }).;

        $("ul.galleria li."+href).each(function() {
                $(this).show("slide", 800);
        });
```

to this:

```
    $("ul.galleria li:visible").hide("slide",function(){
            $("ul.galleria li."+href).stop().show("slide", 800)
     });
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted, but the `show` function executes six times exactly, do you have any idea why?

Comment: you probably need to put a stop() because it builds a queue (you have six :visible elements right?)  . I'll update the code.

Answer (score 4):

Use your call-backs. They run immediately after an effect is finished.

```
$(".item1").slideUp("fast", function(){
  // this is the callback. It will run only when .slideUp completes
  $(".item2").slideDown("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it like so:

```
var counter = 0;
$("ul.galleria li:visible").hide("blind", {direction : "horizontal"},function(){
    counter++;
    if (counter <= 1) {
        $("ul.galleria li."+href).show("blind", {direction : "horizontal"}, 800);
    }
});
```

Thanks for all the help everyone!